# What is the purpose of the stand off on a wall wart?

Tags: wall-wart, regulations

I'm making a device that fits best into the form factor of a wall wart. On some wall warts I've seen they have a little plastic standoff that creates a gap between the case and the wall.

Does that gap serve a purpose or is it just a design choice? My device has a ground plug so it would require a larger and arguably more unsightly standoff. Have you ever seen a device with a ground have a good looking standoff? If so can you please share a photo of how it's done?

[image]

Comment: While it is possible it is there to meet some standard, it may actually exist to give more thickness to the plastic to grab the plug blades, and/or to give space for internal wire connections between a board and the inside ends of the blades.

Comment: Or for airflow.  But I'm guessing.

Comment: I've see wall warts with or without the spacer, so it's a design choice.

Comment: What makes a standoff not "good looking"?

Answer (score 1):

One extremely good reason for the standoff is illustrated by this plug-in air freshener. Without the standoff it would be impossible to insert the device into the socket as the switch would get in the way:

[image]

Other reasons - as suggested in the comments - include pure cosmetic appearance, ventilation, safety, ease of grasping and, doubtless, others. In some countries, part of the standoff may fit into a recess in the wall outlet to provide protection from accidental contact and make it harder for the device to fall out accidentally, and the device may be unusable or unsafe without it.

You need to do a great deal of research into standards and use cases to determine whether your product needs a standoff and, if so, how large. It would be embarrassing to launch a product that a number of people wouldn't be able to use.